# django rest framework model serializers - read nested, write flat

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a situation where my client is attempting to write a representation that includes a list of fk's

```
{
languages: [1]
last_name: "Beecher"
settings: 1
state: "NY"
}
```

But when reading it in, I'd like to have a nested representation to cut back on roundtrips

```
{
languages: [{id:1, created:2013-07-21T01:38:33.569Z, modified:2013-07-21T01:38:33.569Z, language:testing}]
last_name: "Beecher"
settings: {
created: "2013-07-20T22:04:17.998Z"
email_blog: false
email_booking_accepted_denied: false
email_booking_request: false
email_friend_joined: false
email_groups_added_network: false
email_new_review: false
email_news: false
email_upcoming_booking_remind: false
id: 1
mobile_booking_accepted_denied: false
mobile_booking_request: false
mobile_friend_joined: false
mobile_groups_added_network: false
mobile_new_review: false
mobile_upcoming_booking_remind: false
modified: "2013-07-20T22:04:18.000Z"
user: 1
}
state: "NY"
}
```

Reading is no problem using a model serializer and depth=1  - but attempting to write gives an error  "ValueError('instance should be a queryset or other iterable with many=True')"
When attempting to check a many related field for **iter**

Conversely, turning off depth makes writing work just as I'd like, but reading is no good.

Is there something I'm totally missing here? It seems like it should be a simple change, but I can only get one or the other working

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to previous posts, I went with a similar solution based off `get_serializer_class` for this.

I also wanted to be able to change the serializer class depending on method.

First, I added an attribute to the view class with a dictionary mapping request methods to serializer classes.

```py
 serializer_classes = {
     'GET': NestedSerializer,
     'POST': FlatSerializer
 }
```

Then, I defined a mixin to use where I want this behavior.

```py
class SwappableSerializerMixin(object):
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        try:
            return self.serializer_classes[self.request.method]
        except AttributeError:
            logger.debug('%(cls)s does not have the required serializer_classes'
                         'property' % {'cls': self.__class__.__name__})
            raise AttributeError
        except KeyError:
            logger.debug('request method %(method)s is not listed'
                         ' in %(cls)s serializer_classes' %
                         {'cls': self.__class__.__name__,
                          'method': self.request.method})
            # required if you don't include all the methods (option, etc) in your serializer_class
            return super(SwappableSerializerMixin, self).get_serializer_class() es
```

Comment: While this has worked fine before, fails on the first except for the documentation feature on DRF 3.6.3 (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/documenting-your-api/ )

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and it looks like quite a few others have it too. [Carlton Gibson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18787138/537598) answer actually lead me to my hacky solution. I ended up using a [ModelSerializer](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html#specifying-nested-serialization) with the depth set and created the following mixin to use in the views.

```
class ReadNestedWriteFlatMixin(object):
    """
    Mixin that sets the depth of the serializer to 0 (flat) for writing operations.
    For all other operations it keeps the depth specified in the serializer_class
    """
    def get_serializer_class(self, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer_class = super(ReadNestedWriteFlatMixin, self).get_serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.request.method in ['PATCH', 'POST', 'PUT']:
            serializer_class.Meta.depth = 0
        return serializer_class
```

Comment: You may run in to issues as you scale using this approach. Meta is a class level variable, shared by all instances. As you toggle the depth while trying to serialize one object, you mess with ALL instances.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing that occurs to me is to override `get_serializer_class()` on your view for POST/PUT to return a modified serializer not specifying the depth parameter and using a [PrimaryKeyRelatedField](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations.html#primarykeyrelatedfield) for your `languages` field.