# Django Rest Framework - Read nested data, write integer

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

So far I'm extremely happy with Django Rest Framework, which is why I alsmost can't believe there's such a large omission in the codebase. Hopefully someone knows of a way how to support this:

```
class PinSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    item = ItemSerializer(read_only=True, source='item')
    item = serializers.IntegerSerializer(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Pin
```

with the goal

```
The goal here is to read:
{pin: item: {name: 'a', url: 'b'}}
but to write using an id
{pin: item: 10}
```

An alternative would be to use two serializers, but that looks like a really ugly solution:
[django rest framework model serializers - read nested, write flat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769814/django-rest-framework-model-serializers-read-nested-write-flat)

Answer (score 31):

Django lets you access the Item on your Pin with the `item` attribute, but actually stores the relationship as `item_id`. You can use this strategy in your serializer to get around the fact that a Python object cannot have two attributes with the same name (a problem you would encounter in your code).

The best way to do this is to use a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` with a `source` argument. This will ensure proper validation gets done, converting `"item_id": <id>` to `"item": <instance>` during field validation (immediately before the serializer's `validate` call). This allows you to manipulate the full object during `validate`, `create`, and `update` methods. Your final code would be:

```
class PinSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    item = ItemSerializer(read_only=True)
    item_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(write_only=True,
                                                 source='item',
                                                 queryset=Item.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Pin
        fields = ('id', 'item', 'item_id',)
```

Note 1: I also removed `source='item'` on the read-field as that was redundant.

Note 2: I actually find it rather unintuitive that Django Rest is set up such that a Pin serializer without an Item serializer specified returns the item_id as `"item": <id>` and not `"item_id": <id>`, but that is beside the point.

This method can even be used with forward and reverse "Many" relationships. For example, you can use an array of `pin_ids` to set all the Pins on an Item with the following code:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pins = PinSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    pin_ids = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True,
                                                 write_only=True,
                                                 source='pins',
                                                 queryset=Pin.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('id', 'pins', 'pin_ids',)
```

Another strategy that I previously recommended is to use an `IntegerField` to directly set the `item_id`. Assuming you are using a OneToOneField or ForeignKey to relate your Pin to your Item, you can set `item_id` to an integer without using the `item` field at all. This weakens the validation and can result in DB-level errors from constraints being violated. If you want to skip the validation DB call, have a specific need for the ID instead of the object in your validate/create/update code, or need simultaneously writable fields with the same source, this may be better, but I wouldn't recommend anymore. The full line would be:

```
item_id = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)
```

Comment: This could be a comment. You can add more details to make it a good answer.

Comment: Can't be a comment because I don't have 50 reputation. I'll add why it works, but other than that there aren't really any more details that need to be said.

Comment: Sounds like good idea. Otherwise the post may be marked as low quality answer and it may get pushed to review queues.

Comment: is IntegerSerializer deprecated? don't see it in documentation.

Comment: @ShawnAnderson My bad, I didn't notice the typo in the original question. It should be IntegerField, I'll update my answer.

Comment: I agree with Note 2. This drives me crazy.

Comment: Thank you. Excellent answer. DRF is great, however trying to find specific documentation is like looking for a needle in a hayfield

Answer (score 16):

If you are using DRF 3.0 you can implement the new `to_internal_value` method to override the item field to change it to a PrimaryKeyRelatedField to allow the flat writes.  The `to_internal_value` takes unvalidated incoming data as input and should return the validated data that will be made available as `serializer.validated_data`.  See the docs: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#to_internal_valueself-data

So in your case it would be:

```
class ItemSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item

class PinSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    item = ItemSerializer() 

    # override the nested item field to PrimareKeyRelatedField on writes
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
         self.fields['item'] = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Item.objects.all())
         return super(PinSerializer, self).to_internal_value(data)

    class Meta:
        model = Pin
```

Two things to note: The browsable web api will still think that writes will be nested.  I'm not sure how to fix that but I only using the web interface for debug so not a big deal. Also, after you write the item returned will have flat item instead of the nested one.  To fix that you can add this code to force the reads to use the Item serializer always.

```
def to_representation(self, obj):
    self.fields['item'] = ItemSerializer()
    return super(PinSerializer, self).to_representation(obj)
```

I got the idea from this from Anton Dmitrievsky's answer here: [DRF: Simple foreign key assignment with nested serializers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29950956/drf-simple-foreign-key-assignment-with-nested-serializers)

Comment: This comment solved a problem that I spent hours trying to solve. Thank you!

Comment: This is one of the few cases where we shouldn't blindly follow the "Don't Repeat Yourself" philosophy. It's better to repeat lines of code (another serializer class) that are known to have different concerns and will evolve separately. By doing this, we avoid messy workarounds to keep the code in one place.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Customized Serializer Field (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields)

The example took from the link:

```
class ColourField(serializers.WritableField):
    """
    Color objects are serialized into "rgb(#, #, #)" notation.
    """
    def to_native(self, obj):
        return "rgb(%d, %d, %d)" % (obj.red, obj.green, obj.blue)

    def from_native(self, data):
        data = data.strip('rgb(').rstrip(')')
        red, green, blue = [int(col) for col in data.split(',')]
        return Color(red, green, blue)
```

Then use this field in your serializer class.

Comment: In case anyone comes across this later, note that the Field API changed in DRF 3.0. `from_native(self, ob)` is now `to_representation(self, obj)` and `to_native(self, data)` is now `to_internal_value(self, data)`

Comment: Also, `serializers.WritableField` was removed in favor of `serializers.Field`.

Answer (score 1):

I create a Field type that tries to solve the problem of the Data Save requests with its ForeignKey in Integer, and the requests to read data with nested data

This is the class:

```
class NestedRelatedField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
"""
    Model identical to PrimaryKeyRelatedField but its
    representation will be nested and its input will
    be a primary key.
"""

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.pk_field = kwargs.pop('pk_field', None)
    self.model = kwargs.pop('model', None)
    self.serializer_class = kwargs.pop('serializer_class', None)
    super().__init__(**kwargs)

def to_representation(self, data):
    pk = super(NestedRelatedField, self).to_representation(data)
    try:
        return self.serializer_class(self.model.objects.get(pk=pk)).data
    except self.model.DoesNotExist:
        return None

def to_internal_value(self, data):
    return serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField.to_internal_value(self, data)
```

And so it would be used:

```
class PostModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    message = NestedRelatedField(
         queryset=MessagePrefix.objects.all(),
         model=MessagePrefix,
         serializer_class=MessagePrefixModelSerializer
   )
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I refactored [Wezen42](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58504131/20928849)'s answer. So custom field class will look like this:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers


class RepresentativePkRelatedField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    def __init__(self, serializer_class, **kwargs):
        self.serializer_class = serializer_class
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def to_representation(self, value):
        if self.pk_field is not None:
            return self.pk_field.to_representation(value.pk)

        pk = value.pk
        queryset = self.get_queryset().filter(pk=pk)
        if queryset.exists():
            return self.serializer_class(queryset.first()).data
```

And to use that include similar code in your serializer:

```py
profile = RepresentativePkRelatedField(
        queryset=Item.objects.all(),
        serializer_class=ItemSerializer,
    )
```