# How to use serializer to create a new object with a foreignkey

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

suppose this model:

```
class Tweek(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='author')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.content
```

Everthing works fine, now i try to bind a rest api uppon. I've installed the django rest framework and I can retrieve tweeks but I cannot create new ones.

I have this serializer for the Tweek model:

```
class TweekSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Tweek
        fields = ('content', 'date', 'author')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        author_data = validated_data.pop('author')
        author = User.objects.get(username=author_data)

        return Tweek.objects.create(author=author, **validated_data)
```

and the user serializer somply looks like:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name')
```

but the post returns

```
{
    "author": {
        "username": [
            "This field must be unique."
        ]
    }
}
```

I've followed the doc, but i'm lost with this case :(
Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that any field with `unique=True` set, [like the `username` field](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ff8a02ae0b33ee52050e22909d432a3aa060d683/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L298) on the Django `User` model, will automatically have [the `UniqueValidator` added](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#uniquevalidator) to the serializer field. This validator is what is triggering the message you are seeing, and you can remove the validation by setting `validators` to `[]` (an empty list) when initializing the field.

The other issue that you are going to run into is that you are trying to create an object with a foreign key, but you are returning the full serialized object in your response. This issue is easier fixed by using a second field for setting the id, that is write-only, and using the original serializer field for the nested representation and making that read-only.

You can find more information in the following Stack Overflow question: [DRF: Simple foreign key assignment with nested serializers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29950956/359284)