# Django Rest Framework not responding to read_only on nested data

Tags: django-rest-framework

I can't get DRF to allow providing a read_only version of nested data and a writeable version of just the ids in a list in one serializer.  It feels like a bug to me, but usually that just means I'm not understanding the framework well enough, and being misled by the error message.

```
class Individual(models.Model):
  household = models.ForeignKey(
      'household.Household',
      null=True,
      related_name="individuals")
  name = models.CharField(
      max_length=100, default='')

class Household(models.Model):
    address_line1 = models.CharField(max_length=64, default='')

class IndividualListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Individual
        depth = 0
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'name', 'household')
        read_only_fields =  fields

class HouseholdUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    individuals_details = IndividualListSerializer(many=True, source='individuals', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Household
        fields = ('id', 'address_line1', 'individuals', 'individuals_details')
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'individuals_details')
```

The error comes back as

```
AssertionError: The `.update()` method does not support writable nested fields by default. Write an explicit `.update()` method for serializer `household.serializers.HouseholdUpdateSerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields. // Werkzeug Debugger</title>
```

I have used read_only on the nested field (which is needed in the response to the update).  Yet the error still indicates I am not doing so.

If I remove the `individuals` field entirely, the `individuals_details` returns the readable data without the error, but since it's ignoring the `individuals` data being sent, it isn't updating that list.

If I remove the `individuals_details` field, DRF accepts the `individuals` list and performs the update on the model.  But then the return data needed is not there.

So, while either the read nested or write list work on their own, when the other is added the serializer doesn't function.

This seems a pretty common area people get stuck, and it seems the answers [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29950956) have become the best practice for a pattern. But it doesn't work in my code for some reason.  Perhaps because of the ManyToOne in my models.

I can probably work around this by changing the client to perform the PUT for the update, ignore the response, and then do a separate GET, but that's sloppy and shouldn't be needed if the DRF update can be made to work as expected.

What am I missing in this?

Comment: I'm not sure `read_only_fields` is meant to work with explicitly defined fields. What about removing individuals_details from `read_only_fields` ? Does it fixes ?

Comment: Also note that this is an anti pattern to use both a relational field AND a nested serializer to the same model.

Comment: It is not my goal to use both relational and nested.  But DRF doesn't allow me to update just the ID of the nested data. So, what is the good pattern for getting the details on child records after changing which IDs are related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask several questions so I'll start with the representation. Actually you don't need separate field for full `Individual` view you could just ovveride `to_representation` method.

```
class HouseholdUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Household
        fields = ('id', 'address_line1', 'individuals')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super(HouseholdUpdateSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        representation['individuals'] = IndividualListSerializer(instance.individuals.all(), many=True).data
        return representation
```

Usually when you want update related fields of your model you should override `create` and `update` serializer methods.

```
class HouseholdUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ....
    def update(instance, validated_data):
        # get and remove individuals from validated_data
        individuals = validated_data.pop('individuals') 
        # delete all related links to individuals
        # You could provide some validation before clear, check if provided pks exists in db table
        instance.individuals.clear() 
        # update related links with new individuals
        instance.individuals.add(*individuals) 
        # call super to provide update for other fields
        return super(HouseholdUpdateSerializer, self).update(validated_data)
```

`create` will probably works well in your case without overriding. If it not just write it similar to `update`.

Comment: Overriding the to_representation worked for what I needed.  I am not clear on what the second part of overriding the update method is doing.  My guess is that I would also need a custom validator for the individual?

Comment: @shanemgrey sure you could check if `individuals` keys are exists in a db before you clear a links between them. If some key is wrong you'll throw an exception and then catch it in a view layer with `if serializer.is_valid(): ..` expression or with `serializer.save(raise_exception=True)`. You can validate you keys with `queryset.exists()` for each key or check a `len` of you you keys and count keys in a db, like so `if len(individuals) == Individuals.objects.filter(pk__in=individuals).count()`.