# DRF: Reverse foreign key assignment using an array of primary keys

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

As stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29950956/drf-simple-foreign-key-assignment-with-nested-serializers) question

> With Django REST Framework, a standard ModelSerializer will allow ForeignKey model relationships to be assigned or changed by POSTing an ID as an Integer.

I am attempting to update a reverse relationship of the following format:

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

class Quiz(models.Model):
    lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lesson, related_name='quizzes', null=True)

class LessonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    quizzes = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Quiz.objects.all(), many=True, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Lesson
        fields = ('quizzes')
```

When posting an update containing an array of quiz primary keys using `LessonSerializer` I get `TypeError: 'Quiz' instance expected, got '1'`.

Is it possible to assign or change a reverse relationship by POSTing an array of primary keys?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need special field in a serializer, DRF serializers is smart enough to figure out related field from a `fields` value.

```
class LessonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Lesson
        fields = ('quizzes', 'name')
```

And you should pass list of ids, if there is only one value it should be a list anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you need to create a Quiz instance first before you assign it to Lesson. Below's a small change to your code.

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

class Quiz(models.Model):
    lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lesson, related_name='quizzes', null=True)

class LessonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    quizzes = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Quiz.objects.all(), many=True, write_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Lesson
        fields = ('quizzes')

class QuizSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Quiz
        fields = ('name')
```

Create POST request with with quiz then run your post again