# DRF serializer depth makes fields ignored on create

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

[(project is available on github with that problem)](https://github.com/sam-moshenko/drf_depth_problem)

For some reason serializer's depth option makes fields ignored on create.

Serializer:

```
class AnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ('question', 'body',)
        depth = 1
```

View:

```
class AnswerList(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Answer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AnswerSerializer
```

When I try to create an answer with `depth = 1` I get `NOT NULL constraint failed: forum_answer.question_id`, but when I comment out `depth = 1` everything works. But of course I don't get a full `Question` object, only `pk` of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a better solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33048798/3992237)

Now serializer looks like that:

```
class AnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    question_pk = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=Question.objects.all(), source='question', write_only=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ('question', 'question_pk', 'body',)
        depth = 1
```

ps. Also commited to [the project on github.](https://github.com/sam-moshenko/drf_depth_problem)

Comment: What would you do for a ManyToManyField that's also failing because of the same problem with depth

Answer (score 3):

```
class DemoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
def __init__(self, instance=None, data=empty, **kwargs):
    if instance:
        setattr(self.Meta, 'depth', 1)
    else:
        setattr(self.Meta, 'depth', 0)
    super(DemoSerializer, self).__init__(instance, data, **kwargs)

class Meta:
    model = Demo
    fields = '__all__'
    depth = 0
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit why this code solves the issue?

Comment: I had the same problem, and this solution worked! what I'm guessing is that it tests if an object already exists in the db it sets its depth to 1, which means it's a GET request, if it's a POST request, it sets the value to 0 which makes it accept id values in a normal way as it always should be.

Answer (score 1):

**IMPORTANT: I believe this method is very UNSECURE because anyone can edit nested objects.**

You can use [drf-writable-nested](https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested) for such functionality. Updated [the project on github](https://github.com/sam-moshenko/drf_depth_problem) if someone needs.

ps. be sure to use 'pk' field for nested objects if you don't want these objects to be created.

Comment: Hey, sorry to revive such an old thread, but what do you mean by your comment: ```ps. be sure to use 'pk' field for nested objects if you don't want these objects to be created.```