# Serialise an extended User Model in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm extending a django auth user model in a Profile model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    activity = models.IntegerField(default=500)

    def _str_(self):
        return self
```

in my views I'm getting the current auth user and I get the associated profile:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def getUserProfile(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user = request.user)
    serializer = profileSerializer(profile, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Here is my serializers code:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Profile

class profileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('first_name', 'activity')
```

The error I'm getting that Profie object has not a `first_name` attribute, but when I replace `'first_name'` with `'user'` I get only the `id` of the user, so I want to show the `first_name` as well.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to show the fields I wanted using Django [depth](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization) in the serializer

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Profile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name')


class profileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('activity','user')
        depth=1
```

Answer (score 0):

The OneToOneField connects your field `user` in the Profile model to a User object which has a first_name attribute, but in the Profile table that `user` field is just a number that says which User object it is.  To access the first name, you can do this:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Profile

class profileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
```

Then in your template you could display the first_name like this, assuming you pass `person` to it where `person` is an instance of the Profile model:

```html
{{ person.user.first_name }}
```

I also think it would be less confusing to use another name for the field, rather then user.  Call it person maybe, like:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    person = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    activity = models.IntegerField(default=500)

    def _str_(self):
        return self
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works but it is not exactly what I need, I need to use the serializer in my views to return `serializer.data`, but even after applying what you said the `serializer.data` keeps having the `user id` and the `activity` as values, like it is not showing the user fields recursively

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I see that this may be out of my knowledge.  But perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49058931/drf-serializer-depth-makes-fields-ignored-on-create would help?

Comment: Thank you, Yes the solution I found is similar to what is in the link you shared

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class profileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=200, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('user', 'first_name', 'activity')

    def get_first_name(self, obj):
        return User.objects.filter(id=obj.user.id).first().values_list('first_name', flat=True).last()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did found a better solution that I'm going to share