# Rest Framework deserialize one field and serialize model object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Hi I want to deserialize only using 1 field. However, I want to serialize it as an object depending on the model.

Suppose I have:

```
#models.py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()

class Query(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    ...

#serializers.py
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

class QuerySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = ProductSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Query
        fields = '__all__'
```

I want to POST/deserialize something like this on the QuerySerializer:

```
{
    "name": "Query 1",
    "product": "Banana",
    ...
}
```

and I want something like this in return for serializer:

```
{
    "name": "Query 1",
    "product": {
                   "name": "Banana",
                   "amount": 1,
                   "description": "Banana description"
               }
    ...
}
```

I know a way is overriding `to_internal_value` but I do not like it since it messes up with ValidationErrrors.

I also get this as a result:

```
{'product': {'non_field_errors': 
['Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got str.']}}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you pass a payload as `{
    "name": "Query 1",
    "product": "Banana",
    ...
}`  ?

Comment: Well there's only one product named "Banana", I want it get related to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make the **`name`** field of **`Product`** as **`unique`** to avoid unnecessary complications.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()
```

and change your serializer as,

```
class QuerySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Query
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        product_name = validated_data.pop('product')
        product_instance = Product.objects.get(name=product_name)
        return Query.objects.create(product=product_instance, **validated_data)

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super().to_representation(instance)
        rep['product'] = ProductSerializer(instance.product).data
        return rep
```

**Reference:** [**DRF: Simple foreign key assignment with nested serializers?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52246232/12578202)

Comment: I can write `to_representation` inside the ProductSerializer right?

Comment: I didn't get you :(

Comment: Can I override `to_representation` of `ProductSerializer` instread of `QuerySerializer` to get the same result?

Comment: Not in your case. If you do so, you will get the validation error as you've already mentioned in the OP.

Comment: Okay. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, can I ask for more? Why is it not throwing a response error, if there's no data on the product such as `"product": "Apple"`. It is not throwing a response like: `{'product': ['Object with name=Apple does not exist.']}`