# Posting Foreign key to DRF Api using React

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I want to Post the Company object using React. However, the Foreign key seems to be failing. I'm not sure how so I pass the data for address and invoice address.
Below is my code

models.py

```
class Address(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Company(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField()
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                              related_name='address')
    invoice_address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                              related_name='invoice_address')
```

serializers.py

```
class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        exclude = ('id', 'created', 'modified')


class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    address = AddressSerializer()
    invoice_address = AddressSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Company

    def create(self, data):
        #create address if it does not exist
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DRF: Simple foreign key assignment with nested serializers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29950956/drf-simple-foreign-key-assignment-with-nested-serializers)

Comment: more specifically this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/52246232/12578202