# How to write and make correct POST request for nested serializers in DRF?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have two simple models, and serializers for `Course` and `Department` as below: (A course belongs to a department, that is many to one relationship from `Course` to `Department`)

```
# models.py
# Department Model
class Department(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
  location = models.CharField(max_length=1024)

# Course Model
class Course(models.Model):
  code = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
  department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None,
                                   null=True, blank=True)

###################################
# serializers.py
# Department serializer
class DepartmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Department
        fields = ['id', 'name']

# Course serializer
class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    department = DepartmentSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = '__all__'
```

After adding some courses through SQL Queries, I made a `GET` request to the end point `localhost:8000/courses/` which gives the expected result.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "code": "SS240",
    "name": "Sociology",
    "department": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Humanities"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "code": "CS310",
    "name": "Data Structures and Algorithms",
    "department": {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Computer Sciences"
    }
  }
]
```

I want to make a `POST` request to the end point `localhost:8000/courses/`. Say, I have a department with **name = Computer Sciences** with **id = 5**. I want to add a course with **code=CS330, name = Object Oriented Design, department = Computer Sciences**. How should I write the body of the request?

**The following gives the error because of nested representation of department**

```
{
  "code": "CS330",
  "name": "Object Oriented Design",
  "department": 5
}
```

Should it be like this?

```
{
  "code": "CS330",
  "name": "Object Oriented Design",
  "department": {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Computer Sciences"
  }
}
```

How should I overrride the `.create()` method?

Answer (score 1):

Override your **`to_representation(...)`** method of **`CourseSerializer`** class

```
class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = '__all__'

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super().to_representation(instance)
        rep['department'] = DepartmentSerializer(instance.department).data
        return rep
```

**Reference:**

- [**DRF: Simple foreign key assignment with nested serializers?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29950956/drf-simple-foreign-key-assignment-with-nested-serializers)