# DRF: How to hide the password in serializers that use the depth option?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, drf-queryset

I'm using the below serializer for the `User` model, but when I use depth for handling foreign keys, the password shows in the `User` object.

User serializer:

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        read_only_fields = ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',)
        exclude = ('password', )
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'min_length': 4}}
```

In below serializer everything is fine:

```py
class AuditSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, instance=None, **kwargs):
        if instance:
            setattr(self.Meta, 'depth', 10)
        else:
            setattr(self.Meta, 'depth', 0)
        super(AuditSerializer, self).__init__(instance, **kwargs)

    initiator = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Audit
        fields = ['id', 'initiator']
        read_only_fields = ['id', 'initiator']
        depth = 0
```

But in the below that has relation to the previous model/serializer, I have the password issue:

```py
class AuditAttachmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, instance=None, **kwargs):
        if instance:
            setattr(self.Meta, 'depth', 10)
        else:
            setattr(self.Meta, 'depth', 0)
        super(AuditAttachmentSerializer, self).__init__(instance, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = AuditAttachment
        fields = ['id', 'audit']
        read_only_fields = ['id']
        depth = 0
```

Comment: You can not control the fields' nature by using **`depth`** option. For that, you have to use ***nested serialization technique*** (as you have already done that)

Comment: Apart from that, a quick question, For what purpose did you override the **`__init__()`** method like this?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu When I want to add an object by id to `ManyToManyField` the DRF raises an error.

Comment: @ArakkalAbu In the *nested serialization technique*, objects won't be added to the nested fields.

Comment: I would use this method if I had a choice, [DRF: Simple foreign key assignment with nested serializers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52246232/12578202)

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Thank you, the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I delete the `__init__` method and changed it to the below solution.

[DRF: Simple foreign key assignment with nested serializers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62634219/drf-how-to-hide-the-password-in-serializers-that-use-the-depth-option)

Comment: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem using the `depth` Meta attribute. The `password` was integrated in the serialized data.

**1st solution)**

Following @JPG comment on the original post, I've used `to_representation()` method and it works like a charm !

I've ended to this code for the serializer that has a relation with my User model :

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from rest_framework import serializers


class BaseGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        depth = 1
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'user_set',
        )
    
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        response = super().to_representation(instance)
        for user in response.get("user_set"):
            user.pop("password", None)
        return response
```

It simply pops out the password field from each user in my groups.

**2nd solution)**

An other simple solution would be to directly reference the UserSerializer in which you explicitely excluded the password `exclude = ('password',)` (or do not include it).

In my case that would've ended up like this :

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from rest_framework import serializers
from ..serializers.base_user_serializer import BaseUserSerializer


class BaseGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user_set = BaseUserSerializer(many=True)       # <------

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        depth = 1
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'user_set',
        )
```

with the `BaseUserSerializer` as is :

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from ..models.base_user import User


class BaseUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        depth = 1
        fields = (
            'id',
            'username',
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'full_name',
            'full_identification',
            'is_active',
            'groups',
            # 'password' is omitted here
        )
```

Both ways work. The only problem with the second approach is that you, in some cases, face circular imports if you also import this `BaseGroupSerializer` in the `BaseUserSerializer`.

So depending on your case and your limitations with imports,... chose your solution :)