# Trying to relate tables in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

trying to POST request and create new location. now the filed country_id cues many troubles.
those are the classes

```
class Country(models.Model):
id = UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
country_name = CharField(max_length=255)
federal_rate = FloatField()
social_security = FloatField()
comment = CharField(max_length=255)

class Location(models.Model):
participant_id = ForeignKey('Participant', on_delete=CASCADE, related_name="locations")
country_id = ForeignKey('Country', on_delete=CASCADE, related_name="country")
start_date = DateField()
end_date = DateField()
region = CharField(max_length=255)
tax_policy = CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
```

Serializer

```
class CountrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Country
    fields = "__all__"

class LoactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
country_id = CountrySerializer(many=False)

class Meta:
    model = Location
    fields = "__all__"
```

now the only why that I mange to join the tables are adding the country_id line in the seirializer, and whem im trying to create new location, an error occur
this is the way I'm trying to add new location

```
{
"start_date": "2021-10-10",
"end_date": "2021-11-18",
"region": "markian-land",
"tax_policy": "N/A",
"participant_id": "c5c1a00c-4263-418a-9f3a-3ce40a1ea334",
"country_id": "9067e71f-c6b9-4ecc-ad6b-461843063aee"
}
```

the Error - {"country_id": {"non_field_errors": ["Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got str."]}}

when i mange to send as dict, but i have another error that asking for all Country fields, so i get the specific country from data base, and when im sending it i got json error

Comment: It's needless to end Foreign Key field name with **id**. Django does it for you. `country = ForeignKey()` would be OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have more details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52246232/5644965)

**Django Rest Framework** doesn't provide this functionality, you need to create a serializer field first.

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class RelatedFieldAlternative(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.serializer = kwargs.pop('serializer', None)
        if self.serializer is not None and not issubclass(self.serializer, serializers.Serializer):
            raise TypeError('"serializer" is not a valid serializer class')

        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def use_pk_only_optimization(self):
        return False if self.serializer else True

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        if self.serializer:
            return self.serializer(instance, context=self.context).data
        return super().to_representation(instance)
```

Then use this new serializer field in **Location** serializer as,

```
class LoactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    country_id = RelatedFieldAlternative(queryset = Country.objects.all(),
                     serializer=CountrySerializer)

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = "__all__"
```

Please note: You have a typo in `LoactionSerializer`.

Comment: You are the man

Answer (score 0):

this

```
country_id = ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name="country")
```

Comment: Didn't change any thing

Answer (score 0):

You defined country_id as a CountrySerializer in the LocationSerializer and in the CountrySerializer, `fields = "__all__"` means you need to pass all the country object fields to make it work.

Try to delete `country_id = CountrySerializer(many=False)` in the LocationSerializer and try again.

Comment: i can create a new location when i delete this line, but then i dont see the relate country instated just the id

Comment: There are some options to solve this. You can override the create function or you can use a different serializer for reading and writing.