# Django REST Framework: slug or serializer

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am using Django Rest Framework for a project and I have a nested serializer like this:

```
class TopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contact = (something goes here)
    email = (something goes here)
```

For POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE I want to specify these values with a slug. Suppose each class (Contact, Email) has a member called `resource_id` and that is my slug. For these methods I could use:

```
class TopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contact = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=False, slug_field='resource_id')
    email = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=False, slug_field='resource_id')
```

However, for GET I want to return the embedded objects too, so I could use:

```
class TopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contact = ContactSerializer(read_only=True)
    email = EmailSerializers(read_only=True)
```

So how do I specify in my serializer that `contact` can be either a slug or a serialized object? Is there a way to do this with just one serializer or must I have two different serializers and use the `request.method` in the view to select which serializer I use?

Or, should I use something like this:

```
class TopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contact = ContactSerializer(read_only=True)
    email = EmailSerializers(read_only=True)
    contact_rid = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=False,slug_field=resource_id,queryset=models.Contact.objects.all())
    email_rid = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=False,slug_field=resource_id,queryset=models.Email.objects.all())
```

This way I can use `contact_rid` and `email_rid` for POST/PATCH/PUT/DELETE and get contact and email fields back in GET.

Am I on the right track? Other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Check out custom fields https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields
You could define a custom serializer fields that overrides `serializers.Field` and overrride `to_representation` to return the fully serialized object and `to_internal_value` to mimic the behavior of a slugRelatedField.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track!

Use one related field for write and another to read the full object is a good approach if you need more details for related objects.

You can also add to the slug field the flag `write_only=True` if you want the field is used only for write. However, checking this option will not hint selected objects when you are under an update route in Browseable API

Check [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37529772/7727181)